# Connect Remote Desktop via putty

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, putty, windows-server-2012

I am using `Windows 7` as a client system and remote desktop was `Windows server 2012`. I am not able to connect remote system through `Putty` from my local system. It shows `Network connection time out`. I have my remote desktop `IP Address` and Administrator username and password.

```
IpAddress = MyAddress
UserName = MyName
Password = MyPassword
```

How can I connect remote system from my local system using `Putty`.

If anyone knows something, can you please suggest it to me clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured SSH or tenet on the server?

Comment: No. I don't know How to configure. Can you explain.

Comment: Putty is just a tool to establish a telnet or SSH connection

Comment: I would suggest Googling it if you don't know How to set it up

Comment: Also please note that if you read the wiki for the putty tag you would have found your issue http://superuser.com/tags/putty/info

Comment: @50-3 I did upto step-8 in this [Link](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/install-SSH-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html).After I didn't understand.How do I test the connection. can you check it once.

Comment: after figure 8 make sure your services are up and running but you should now be able to use putty to connect to your server just make sure SSH and port 22 are selected

Answer (score 3):

I think the wider issue is... you're using a tool without knowing how to use it.

Putty is a client for a variety of remote access tools, none of which are natively supported on windows. There are SSH servers you can install on your servers, but most of them seem to be hobby projects that arn't very well supported.

You *need* a SSH server (or telnet but no, just no for that), or some other protocol putty supports to use putty. None of this is native on windows (well, nothing worth using anyway - there may be a telnet server, but its an insecure, protocol that you don't want to be using).

The 'right' tool for CLI remote access to another windows system is WinRM - setup is PRETTY involved so you might want to look it up - this will let you use powershell commands to the remote system. RDP might be a simpler solution.